# Replacing javascript shortcodes to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, shortcode

I have a web page with some text and shortcodes. I would like to replace shortcodes to links :

```
[a href="http://www.myurl.com" title="A Link Title"]My link text[/a] and even here [a href="www.yoururl.com" title="Another link" class="linkClass"]This is cool to[/a] !
```

To this

```
<a href="http://www.myurl.com" title="A Link Title">My link text</a> and even here <a href="www.yoururl.com" title="Another link" class="linkClass">This is cool to</a> !
```

Could you help me to do this in JQuery or Javascript ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We won't help you write things like this yourself, but we can help if you get stuck with a specific problem while trying to do it, I suggest you take a look at the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to see what kind of questions stackoverflow is for and which ones aren't received well here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?
Should I give you what I try to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do this with this script : https://github.com/nicinabox/shortcode.js

Here is my code to handle my case :

```
new Shortcode(document.querySelector('body'), {
  a: function(done) {
    var ret='<a';
    if (typeof this.options.href !== 'undefined' && this.options.href !== null) ret+=' href="'+this.options.href+'"';
    if (typeof this.options.class !== 'undefined' && this.options.class !== null) ret+=' class="'+this.options.class+'"';
    if (typeof this.options.title !== 'undefined' && this.options.title !== null) ret+=' title="'+this.options.title+'"';
    if (typeof this.options.style !== 'undefined' && this.options.style !== null) ret+=' style="'+this.options.title+'"';
    if (typeof this.options.target !== 'undefined' && this.options.target !== null) ret+=' target="'+this.options.title+'"';
    ret+='>'+this.contents+'</a>';
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **replace** . Hope it will help.

```
function sayHello() {
   var str = '[a href="http://www.myurl.com" title="A Link Title"]My link text[/a] and even here [a href="www.yoururl.com" title="Another link" class="linkClass"]This is cool to[/a] !';

   while(str.includes("[")){
      str = str.replace("[", "<");
   }

   while(str.includes("]")){
      str = str.replace("]", ">");
   }

   console.log(str);
}
sayHello();
```